# showing all types of uploaded files in grid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to make an e-learning webpage for my organization. 
I want to upload .doc/.docx,.ppt/.pptx, .pdf and video files on my server and want to show the details in a grid. I am using mvc for this but I am new in mvc. 
So I am not getting that how to do it. 
I also want to show the file content on clicking event of a link button.
Please help me to create this page and also share if any link which can help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be good to start reading about MVC and try your hands with some simple implementations. Once you get comfort with simple you can explore to make it complex. What you are asking here is not a simple solution. You need to try yourself something and come back here if you face any specific issue.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok thanks you all.